# JS countdown timer with cookie issues

Tags: javascript, counter, countdown

We have a 24 hour countdown timer. Problem is, whenever the page is refreshed the timer restarts. How can we create a cookie so it doesn't restart for the same user/when refreshed? And if if goes down to 0 restarts again?

**What we have so far:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var totalSeconds;
function initiate(seconds) 
{
  totalSeconds = parseInt(seconds);
  setInterval("timeUpdate()", 1000); 
}
function timeUpdate() 
{
   var seconds = totalSeconds;
   if(seconds > 0) 
   {
          totalSeconds--; 
          var hours= Math.floor(seconds/3600);
          seconds %= 3600;
          var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
          seconds %= 60;
          var timeIs = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + ((minutes < 10) ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":" + ((seconds < 10) ? "0" : "") + seconds;
          document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = "" + timeIs;
   }
   else 
   {
          document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = '';
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '';
   }
}
initiate(24 * 60 * 60);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   document.cookie="name=" + cookievalue;
   alert("Setting Cookies : " + "name=" + cookievalue );
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm)

Comment: How do I use this? Where? Can you show how to put those pieces of code together on the page? Thank you for the help!

Comment: you can get see an example in the link

Answer (score 0):

First we need to have functions to set and read cookies. For this use the functions given in this answer [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825695/986141)

So, we have two functions `createCookie` and `setCookie` in our code.

Now set and get cookie on page load as given below

```
var
    //Get time started
    timeStarted = getCookie('timeStarted'),
    //To store total seconds left
    totalSeconds,
    //Current Time
    currentTime = parseInt(new Date()/1000),
    //Timer Length
    timerLength = 24 * 60 * 60;

if(timeStarted == "") {

    //Time not yet started. Start now.
    createCookie('timeStarted', currentTime, 365);

    //We started time just now. So, we have full timer length remaining
    totalSeconds = timerLength;

} else {

    //Calculate total seconds remaining
    totalSeconds = timerLength - (currentTime - timeStarted)%(timerLength);
}
```

Now initialize as given below

```
initialize(totalSeconds);
```

Both your functions work fine and keep them.

I used 365 days as the cookie period. We just need the start time.

Change the code as per your requirements.

Let me know if you need any clarification about this code.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a novice on this. Where do I put the initialize(totalSeconds); exactly?

Comment: I tried adding the first piece of code, and the cookie code, and set and get as you stated above, then body onload initialize(totalSeconds);
 but the timer restarts on page refresh. Would you be so kind as to put all the blocks of code together the way I should use it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hope you are running the file from a server and cookies are enabled in the browser. Files running from a server can only play with cookies. You can put initialize(totalSeconds); at the end. So, it's some thing like, all functions come first and then the given code and then initialize.